# Undirected graph find minimal wight sum so every cycle has at least one weighted edge included

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I am given weighted undirected and non-planar graph G=(V,E). I don't understand much about complex graph and how to work with them. So any tips will help.

For example like this
[image: input]

I don't know how to explain it but i will try.
Result should me like this: In every simple cycle (for example A-B-C-A) there should be at least one weighted edge, but weight sum for all cycles should be minimum. (One edge can belong to more than one cycle and one cycle can have more than one weighted edge). And it should be done in polynomial time.

Result for previous given graph will look like this
[image: result]
 Sum will be 6.

Thank for any tip!

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Normally when we talk about a weighted graph, _every_ edge has a weight, so what do you mean by every cycle containing at least one weighted edge?

Comment: I will try to explain differently. I have to find a set of edges with minimal weight sum, so that every simple cycle in graph contains at least one edge of this set.

Comment: Your example is a planar graph... So is the input planar or non-planar?

Comment: @j_random_hacker For undirected graph, it is equivalently finding the maximum spanning tree.

Comment: @xskxzr: You're right, not sure how I missed that!  Deleted that comment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10791689/783245 may help.